# How to store reactive form data to localstorage?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I want to store reactive forms data to local storage and access that data to another page.

```
<form [formGroup]="testform" >
      firstname:
          <input type="text" formControlName="fname"><br>
      lastname:
          <input type="text" formControlName="lname">
          <button type="submit" (click)="Submit(testform)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I hope anyone knows the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Do you face any issue to do that?

Comment: i dont know how to do that

Comment: Check the posted answer

Comment: You should store the data in a service instead of local storage

Comment: will u explain how to do that?

Comment: how do you repatch the reactive form, after receiving values from local storage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the value:

**JSON.stringify()** is needed if you are storing an object.

```
localStorage.setItem('form-data', JSON.stringify(this.testform.value));
```

and to get the stored object from localStorage:

```
let formValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('form-data'))
```

Comment: how to display values to console

Comment: `console.log(formValue)`